# React.JS : make fetch to populate select

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a fetch to populate my select, but I can't use the fetch..

```
const loadOptions = async (searchQuery, loadedOptions, { page }) => {
    const requestMethod = {
                method: "PUT",
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                body: { realmIds: [props.realmScelto] }
            };
    
            const response = await fetch('myapi', requestMethod) // error is here, in requestMethod

            // const response = await axios.post(`myapi?page=${page}&size=20`, { realmIds: [props.realmScelto] }) // this works.. it gives me back 1 value, and it ok but add always the same value that I obtain from api

            // const optionToShow = await response.data
            const optionToShow = await response.json()
 return {
            options: optionToShow,
            hasMore: optionToShow.length >= 1,
            additional: {
                page: searchQuery ? 2 : page + 1,
            },
        };
    };

    const onChange = option => {
        if (typeof props.onChange === 'function') {
            props.onChange(option);
        }
    };

    return (
        <AsyncPaginate
            value={props.value}
            loadOptions={loadOptions}

            onChange={onChange}
            isSearchable={true}
            placeholder="Select"
            additional={{
                page: 0,
            }}
        />
    );
```

The error that I receive in the requestMethod is:

> The argument of type '{method: string; headers: {'Content-Type':
> string; }; body: {realmIds: any []; }; } 'is not assignable to the
> parameter of type' RequestInit '.   The types of the 'body' property
> are incompatible.
> The type '{realmIds: any []; } 'is not assignable to type' BodyInit '.
> In type '{realmIds: any []; } 'The following properties of type' URLSearchParams' are missing: append, delete, get, getAll and 4 more.

Answer (score 0):

For `fetch`, the `body` you pass in is not converted to JSON automatically.

Try

```
const requestMethod = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({ realmIds: [props.realmScelto] })
};
const response = await fetch(`myapi?page=${page}&size=20`, requestMethod)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have tried this but it gives me a 403... while if I use axios with the "same structure" it works..

Comment: make sure the PUT method is allowed. You're using POST with axios. You could try using `method: 'POST'`

Comment: @Jack23 your axios request url and http method is different.

Comment: Ok you have rigth I have tried with POST in fetch but the result is the same.
@Deniz 
what are you referring to ( don't consider ?page=${page}&size=20 that is something that I should implement when the fetch works=

Comment: @Jack23 maybe there's an axios interceptor that sets an authorization token. Are you sure requested endpoint of api doesn't need authorization?

Comment: It should be.. I have use fetch for all get that I have done.. but now with the post I receive only 403 :/